# Why is PhantomCSS moving the HTML elements around?

Tags: testing, web, phantomjs, regression-testing, backstop.js

Problem: when I use a visual regression testing tool such as PhantomCSS, the screenshots produced contain the website with dramatically moved HTML elements.

Problem image:
[image: Image of <nav> by PhantomCSS]

How it should really look like: (taken from esfiddle.net )

[image: Actual <nav>]

Tools: PhantomCSS. The same problem happens with BackstopJS.

What can I do to prevent the problem image?

Answer (score 0):

The *flex* CSS property is causing the problems.

Answer (score 0):

Since version 3 backstop supports chrome as engine, so you could specify

```
"engine": "chrome"
```

I think it would work fine in Chrome.

Comment: PS: @EugeneFedotov, please help with [configuring ports](//stackoverflow.com/q/46201755/4928642).